# PHP implode invalid arguements

Tags: php

I am using the PHP function:

```
implode(',',$emails_list)
```

`$emails_list` is an array in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($records as $contacts2)
    {
        //generate the list of emails address in an array
        if(filter_var($contacts2["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $emails_list[] = $contacts2["email"];
        }
    }
```

but i am getting this error when there is only one row returned in the `$emails_list` variable

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed
```

UPDATE:

I have just changed my loop to be:

```
foreach ($records as $contacts2)
    {
        //generate the list of emails address in an array
        if(filter_var($contacts2["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $emails_list = $contacts2["email"].', '.$emails_list;
        }
    }
```

but if there is just one `$contacts2["email"]` it does:

```
email@domain.com,
```

how can i stop the `,` being at the end if there is just the one email address?

Comment: Can you make a var_dump() of your $emails_list plz? and show us

Comment: I don't see where you set `$emails_list` as an array so if no values pass your filter_var it will not be an array and cause your error

Comment: Please print out `gettype($emails_list)` right before you implode it and let us know what you get

Comment: When building the array, do an echo after you add each email to emails_list showing the email value.

If that returns, do a var_dump of emails_lists (As suggested).

Otherwise, simply stop using the array - if you're making an array just to implode it, why not just build a string in the first place?

$emails_list = $emails_list . ', ' $newemail

Or similar.

Comment: If you `var_dump($emails_list)`, what do you get?

Comment: doing a var_dump i get array(0) { }

Comment: What you you get if you try `var_dump($contacts2)` at the first line of your foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is now a different question altogether - but you would add this right after your loop has completed:

```
if( ! empty($emails_list)) { 
    $emails_list = substr($emails_list, 0, -2); // removes last 2 characters from end of string
}
```

Comment: why empty - does that not mean that if the whole variable is empty?

Comment: It checks to see if it is not set or an empty string. I don't know whether you are declaring or modifying it somewhere outside of your sample code, so I took the safest option. See http://uk1.php.net/empty

Answer (score -1):

Before the foreach, put this line:

```
$emails_list = array()
```

It should help.

Comment: Yes but that's another question - it's the logic behind. Show me the input of the foreach.